# Error while excecuting UDF in PIG

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am trying to run my first UDF using the example

http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual.
Now i have my 
FirstUdf.jar,myscript.pig both in same folder

My myscript.pig is as follows

```
  REGISTER FirstUdf.jar; A = LOAD '/home/vishal/exampleforPIG1' AS
 (exchange: chararray, symbol: chararray, date: int,value:float);
```

B =FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.UPPER(symbol);

DUMP B;

Now when i am giving the following command to run my script it gives me the following error

Command--

> java -cp FirstUdf.jar home/vishal/FirstUdf.jar -x local myscript.pig

Following Error--

> ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  "java ""
>   at line 1, column 1.

Am i giving the command wrong or what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may try the followings:

Hardcode the path to the custom UDF you have:

```
REGISTER '/path/to/FirstUdf.jar';
DEFINE myUDF com.example.MyUDF();
...

Then:
pig -f myscript.pig -x local
```

...or pass it as a command line argument:

```
REGISTER '$UDF_PATH/FirstUdf.jar';
DEFINE myUDF com.example.MyUDF();
...

Then:
pig -f myscript.pig -param UDF_PATH=/path/to -x local
```

Comment: HI Lonard,  Thanks for the reply....I have one more doubt as to whether the 'Firstudf.jar should be in piggybank or anywhere

Comment: Firstudf.jar shouldn't be in the Piggybank directory, just pick an appropriate place where you store your custom jars.

Comment: @vishal1985 On the other hand could please revert the question to the original one you asked because now the question and my answer aren't in sync. The whole thing looks like a bit ambiguous. Just create a new question for further problems you encountered.

Comment: Under you user profile / activity tab you can see your question's revision